# Parse data using Alamofire and SwiftyJson

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

My **JSON** -

```
"documents": {
        "driver": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Driving Licence",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": {
                    "id": 9,
                    "provider_id": 165,
                    "document_id": "1",
                    "url": "https://boucompany.com/storage/provider/documents/b92cf551a62b6b8c183997b41b9543c6.jpeg",
                    "unique_id": null,
                    "status": "ACTIVE",
                    "expires_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2019-04-26 19:05:58",
                    "updated_at": "2019-04-27 06:37:56"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Bank Passbook",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Joining Form",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": null
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Work Permit",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": null
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Test Document",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": null
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "NID Card",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": null
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Matrícula",
                "type": "DRIVER",
                "provider_document": null
            }
        ],
```

I want to parse the **url** name.I have used **Alamofire** and **SwiftyJson** in my project. So far i have tried -

```
self.documentsDriver = json["documents"]["driver"][0]["provider_document"]["url"].stringValue
```

How can i print the value or "url" using **swiftyjson**

Comment: Do you want to get status or url?

Comment: Status or url anthing from "provider_document" object @RajeshKumarR

Comment: Are you sure the json will still be same? Why don't you rather create a model properly,  then conform it to a `Decodable` and finally iterate through the `.driver` array searching for the needed one?

Comment: @Astoria yes i can use the model property but isn't there any way to parse data using the above swiftyJson structure?

Comment: @MdRashedPervez what if tomorrow this driver will be at "3" position? Take a look at the Kamran's brilliant approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Encodable` to parse this response as below,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let documents: Documents
}

struct Documents: Codable {
    let driver: [Driver]
}

struct Driver: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, type: String
    let providerDocument: ProviderDocument?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, type
        case providerDocument = "provider_document"
    }
}

struct ProviderDocument: Codable {
    let id, providerID: Int
    let documentID: String
    let url: String
    let status: String
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case providerID = "provider_id"
        case documentID = "document_id"
        case url
        case status
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

To parse the response,

```
   let jsonData = Data() // Your API response data. 
   let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)

   response.documents.driver.forEach { driver in
      print(driver.providerDocument?.url)
   }
```

Comment: @Kamram brother ..thanks for your answer. Is there any way to parse the JSON using swiftyJson?

Comment: What are you getting from the attempt in question?

Answer (score 1):

Parse JSON data using SwiftyJSON

```
func convertJSONToDriverModel(json: JSON) {
    if let driver = json["documents"]["driver"].array {
        for driverJson in driver {
            let driverObj = convertToDriverJSONModel(json: driverJson)
            print(driverObj)
        }
    }
}

func convertToDriverJSONModel(json: JSON) {
    let name = json["name"].string ?? ""
    if let providerDetails = json["provider_document"].dictionary {
        let url = convertToProductDetailsJSONModel(json: JSON(providerDetails))
        print("URL is: \(url)")
    }
}

// Method to parse data inside provider_document (Here I have parsed only url)
func convertToProviderDocumentJSONModel(json: JSON) -> String {
    let url = json["url"].string ?? ""
    return url
}
```